# Extract one word after a specific word on the same line but there is no space between them

Tags: bash, shell, unix

How can I extract a word that comes after a specific word in bash ? More precisely, I have a file which has a  line which looks like this:

```
IN=../files/d.txt
```

i want to read "d" from above line.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="files/") print $(i+1)}' inputFile
```

this code not helping me becouse it is trying to reach word after space. but here we have "d" after "files/" (continue word) and end with "."

Comment: Can you have more words on one line? `IN=../files/d.txt; OUT=../files/e.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/\/files\// s~.*/files/\([^.]*\)\..*~\1~p' file
```

```
d
```

You may also use `awk` command:

```
awk -F/ '$(NF-1) == "files"{sub(/\..*/, "", $NF); print $NF}' file
```

Comment: Thank you but this code keeping other lines too.. Like in this file having many lines but we want to pick word after "files/" till "." and remove all ..

Comment: Here we are reading till "." if word is "demo.txt"  but problem is some time we dont have "." at end its just work "demo" So given code where i need to do changes ?

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide all possible inputs with expected outputs so that I can understand it better

Comment: if word is "demo.txt" then  we need to  read till "." So o/p will be "demo" but problem is some time we have data like "demo" where we dont have "." thats why i need read this single word as ""demo".  in given  code where i need to do changes for both scenario?

Comment: string in file is "IN=../files/demo.txt" So o/p shoud be "demo" But some time we got file like "IN=../files/demo" so  o/p shoud be "demo". but as per above code we reading till "." which is missing in second  Scenario..

Comment: Use: `sed -En '/\/files\// s~.*/files/([^.]+)(\..*){0,1}~\1~p' file`

Comment: I don't even have `-e` option in my `sed`

Comment: its there "-En", can we write code  for only if "IN=../files/demo" so o/p shoud be "demo"..

Comment: can we code if  "IN=../files/demo" so o/p shoud be "demo" ? "." is not much needed now..

Comment: I have tried to provide every possible help to you but cannot understand those cryptic comments. Please create a separate question to see if someone more knowledgeable can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use look behind (?<=match-before here) to this.

```
 echo "IN=../files/d.txt" | grep -Po "(?<=files\/)\w+"
```

Results:

```
d
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bash pattern substitution and `basename` (as your input data looks like a filename):

```
basename ${IN%.*}
```